# laravel 5 routing for admin (dizzy)

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5, admin

How to correct? That's all intertwined url?

```
/admin/* (if auth and id user **!=** 1 redirect '/')
/admin/* (if **NO** auth redirect '/admin/login')
/admin/{page} (if auth and id user **==** 1) redirect /admin/{page}
```

Comment: You need to be more descriptive about your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Route Group which you can call admin and and create the confirmation, then add a prefix to the route for example:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{

    Route::get('user', function()
    {
        // place your routes here
    });

});
```

[Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups)

Comment: How to?
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{

   if no check auth to ANY routing go '/'
example :
Route::get('/*', function() // how any patch
    {
        // place your routes here
    });

});